# Determine entry in data.frame closest to a specified value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an input "value" and i want to find out the nearest value from the first two columns of the below data frame in `R`

```
value = 20003
```

data

```
  Min_Benefs   Max_Benefs  MSR_Min   MSR_Max
  5000         5999        0.039     0.036
  6000         6999        0.036     0.034
  7000         7999        0.034     0.032
  8000         8999        0.032     0.031
  9000         9999        0.031     0.03
  10000        14999       0.03      0.027
  15000        19999       0.027     0.025
  20000        49999       0.025     0.022
  50000        59999       0.022     0.02
  60000        0.02                  0.02
```

Expected output

```
20000
```

Tried:

```
closestLoc = which(min(abs(data[,c(1,2)]-value)))
closestVal = data[,c(1,2)][which(min(abs(data[,c(1,2)]-value)))]
```

So, i want to find out the nearest number of my input "value" from the first two columns of the data frame "data". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a single vector from the two columns with `unlist()`, and consequently find the nearest value in it:

```
vec <- unlist(df[,c(1,2)]) # create vector
vec[which.min(abs(vec - value))] # find nearest value
#Min_Benefs8 
#      20000
```

Answer (score 0):

Save computation time and only provide a boolean vector. All these nested stuff make your code less readable, imho.

```
blah <- data.frame(x = seq.int(10)*1000, y = seq.int(10)*1000 + 999)

tmpin <- 9003
blah %>% dplyr::filter(x <= tmpin & y > tmpin)
# OR
blah[with(blah, x <= tmpin & y > tmpin),]
# OR
base::subset(blah, x <= tmpin & y > tmpin)
```

Edit: I misunderstood the question in the beginning. Nevertheless, a simple extension can be done:

```
blah %>% 
  dplyr::filter(x <= tmpin & y > tmpin) %>%
  summarise(minum = ifelse(x + y > 2*tmpin, x ,y))
```

but it is not as short as suggested in the other answer.